# How can I read the content of a file and append it to an string to latter add it into the html?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm trying this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < nFiles; i++) {
        datos += "<pre>Archivo " + (i+1) +": "+ files[i].name  + "  Tamaño: " + files[i].size +" bytes " + "  Tipo: " + files[i].type + "  Última modificación: " + files[i].lastModifiedDate+ "</pre>" ;
        var text = "test";
        if (files[i].type.match(/text.*/)) {
            var lector = new FileReader();
            lector.onload = function (evento) {
                text = lector.result;
          }      
        lector.readAsText(files[i]);
        datos += "<pre>" + text + "</pre>";
        }
        else {
            alert("Error : ¡¡¡ File not valid !!!");
        }
    }

document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML = datos;
```

But it always writes "test" in the HTML. However, the other properties from the file appear correctly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong reading the file. Please I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED ANSWER:

One has to make sure that `datos` is being appended after the lector finished. So, this line should be inside 'onload' event handler:

```
    if (files[i].type.match(/text.*/)) {
        let lector = new FileReader();
        lector.readAsText(files[i]);
        lector.onload = function (evento) {
            text = lector.result;
            datos += "<pre>" + text + "</pre>";
      }
```

But even that is not enough. In original code the update of page element is 'not waiting' for these 'onload' events to occur, so it is currently done before the lector results are applied to `datos`.

The simplest way to fix this is to add little delay before writing to the page, by changing the last line to this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML = datos;
}, 100)
```

where 100 is 100 milliseconds to wait before all cycles are over. You can experiment and make this number even smaller may be.

And one should also use `let lector = new FileReader();` instead of `var lector = new FileReader();`, otherwise when it comes to the line `text = lector.result;` we only would have the lector object from the latest file.

Try it.

Comment: That gives an error:

Ejercicio13.html:24 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.
    at calcularTamañoArchivos (http://localhost/Ejercicio13/Ejercicio13.html:24:16)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (http://localhost/Ejercicio13/Ejercicio13.html:40:104)

Comment: Have you removed the second call of  `lector.readAsText(files[i]);` that was in your original code? May be you now have two calls and the second one gives this error? You only need single one.

Comment: Yes, I removed it

Comment: I've just add more to my answer. Hope this should help.

Comment: And I was wrong about that lector.readAsText should go before onload. It doesn't really matter. But better it should be inside if block anyway.

Comment: This works but only if I load 1 file, if I load 2 files or more it only shows de last one. Do you know what can I do so it shows all the files? Thank you!

Comment: I have a suspiction, that this is because you use `var lector`, so there is only one lector object at the same time and when you assign `var lector = new FileReader();` it actually replaces the 'content' of the same exact var with new reader object. I would try to rewrite it like this: `let lector = new FileReader();` . Using let should make each lector to live separately in each loop scope. Try it.

Comment: Thats true! I forgot to change that var to let, Thank you so much!